# how could upload file to server when I used Vue.js in Filemanager plunig or how can call global function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

how could upload file to server when I used Vue.js in Filemanager plunig?

I tried to more methods and console log display upload successful, but I cannot see any file in server, who knows what's happen?

```
<template>
  <div class="FileManagement" id="file-manager" name="file-manager">
    <va-inner-loading :loading="isLoading">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="flex xs12 md12">
          <DxFileManager
            ref="fileManager"
            name="file"
            :file-system-provider="fileSystemProvider"
            current-path="Widescreen"
          >
            <DxPermissions
              :create="true"
              :copy="false"
              :move="false"
              :delete="true"
              :rename="false"
              :upload="true"
              :download="true"
            />
          </DxFileManager>
        </div>
      </div>
    </va-inner-loading>
  </div>
</template>
data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      // fileSystemProvider: [],
      popupVisible: false,
      imageItemToDisplay: {},
      result: [],
      fileSystemProvider: new CustomFileSystemProvider({
        getItems,
        createDirectory,
        uploadFileChunk,
        onCurrentDirectoryChanged,
        downloadItems,
        renameItem,
        deleteItem,
      }),
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initEvent();
  },
  methods: {
}

function uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {
  let self = this;
let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("name", fileData.name);
  formData.append("file", fileData);

  let config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  };

  axios.post("/files/upload", formData, config).then(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log(response.data);
    }
  });
}
```

in my global.vue, I have a this function, but how can call this function in my fileManager.vue out of methods()?

```
Global.vue
onUploadFile: function (
//code
) 

FileManager.vue
mounted() {},
methods: {},
function uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {
 // how can call global onUploadFile: function  ???
}
```

General

Request URL: http://192.168.1.120/files/upload/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 192.168.1.120:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

```
or may I use javascript mehtods to upload the file?

====================================================================

to RuNpiXelruN, I did your methods to modify my code, and it was show me successful, but the server still didn't had file.
```

General

Request URL: http://192.168.1.120/files/upload/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address: 192.168.67.164:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Answer (score 0):

@James fyi you do the below

```
formData.append("file", fileData, fileData.name)
```

otherwise how about changing the header to the below and see if you have any success.

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Comment: I tried to used your methods, but it's still show me successful and the server didn't had file.